# Python: Webdriver get list of the URLs, duplicated data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pull the hist data from a URL. The date(as epcho time) is part of the URL.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from datetime import datetime
options = Options()
options.headless = True

lastDate = '2021-07-01'
firstDate = '2010-01-01'
time_object = time.strptime(lastDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
period2 = int(time.mktime(time_object))
period1 = int(period2 - 86400*200)
time_object = time.strptime(firstDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
period0 = time.mktime(time_object)
count = 1
url=f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
#url=r'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?period1=1262304000&period2=1625097600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true'
while period2 >= period0:
    ed = datetime.fromtimestamp(period2)
    sd = datetime.fromtimestamp(period1)
    print(f"Working on {sd} {ed}, current count {count}")
    print(f"URL is {url}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get(url)
    js = "var q=document.documentElement.scrollTop=100000" 
    driver.execute_script(js)
   
    for row in t.tbody.findAll('tr'):
        date = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        date = datetime.strptime(date, "%b %d, %Y")
        date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        open = row.findAll('td')[1].text.replace(',','')
        high = row.findAll('td')[2].text.replace(',','')
        low = row.findAll('td')[3].text.replace(',','')
        close = row.findAll('td')[4].text.replace(',','')
        adjclose = row.findAll('td')[5].text.replace(',','')
        volume = row.findAll('td')[6].text.replace(',','')
        hist = pd.DataFrame([[date,open,high,low,close,adjclose,volume]], columns=['Date', 'Open','High','Low','Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volumn'])
        if count == 1:
            hist.to_csv('hist.csv', index=False, header=True)
        else:
            hist.to_csv('hist.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)  
        
        count = count + 1    

    period2 = int(period1)
    period1 = int(period2 - 86400*200)
    url=f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    driver.close()
```

I printed the URL, it updated properly with the newly refreshed period. However, what's being written to my hist.csv is duplicated. It seems the driver only respected my first URL and completely ignored the rest. As a result I got the first period of the dates/price etc repeatedl in my hist.csv

Appreciate if you have any comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard - I just realized I didn't refresh the variable while I'm using jupyter. i found the problem just 2 minutes after I posted the questions. Thanks for the great stackoverflow!